# How to store states for sub-modules when using "The Elm Architecture"

Tags: web, functional-programming, reactive-programming, elm

I'm new to `Function Programming(FP)` and [Elm](http://elm-lang.org), so thinking in FP way is quite challenging for me.

I'm working on a web-app which is very similar to the example of [Elm Tutorial](http://www.elm-tutorial.org).

For the sake of simplicity, we assume the `sub-module` is a counter.
It will display an initial value of 0 and two buttons to increase/decrease that value.

```
,---.     ,---.
| + | 123 | - |
`---'     `---'
```

And simplified version of my app is shown below:

```hs
-------------------------------------
type alias Model =
    { contents : List Contents.Content
    , routing : Routing
    }

type Routing = List | Edit Int

view : Model -> Html
view model =
    case model.routing of 
        Edit id -> 
            let 
                maybe = List.head << (List.filter (\c -> c.id == id)) model.contents
            in 
                case maybe of 
                    Just content -> Contents.EditView content
                    Nothing -> div [] [ text "Error" ]

        List -> Contents.listView model.contents
------------------------------------
module Contents where 

type alias Content = { someKey : SomeType }

editView : Content -> Html
editView content =
    div []
        [ Counter.view WHERE_SHOULD_I_GOT_A_Counter.Model_FOR_THIS_CALL
        , someOtherViews content
        ]


listView : List Content -> Html
listView = 
    listViewImp
---------------------------
module Counter where

type alias Model = Int

view : Model -> Html
view model =
    div []
        [ button [] [ text "+" ]
        , text (toString model)
        , button [] [ text "-" ]
        ]
```

There is three-level view hierarchy :

```
main view ----> edit view --> counter
            |-> list view
```

The counter value should be 0 every time I navigate to `edit view` from other views, and then it should be modified only by clicking those two buttons until I leave that page.

The question is where should I get a Counter.Model to pass to Counter.view?

1. Because the counter is totally independent, so I don't want top level view to know its existence, so it can't be sent from `view` function.
2. If I initialize a Counter.Model in `editView` function, every call to `editView` (invoked by other actions maybe) will re-initialize the counter to 0

I hope that I have made myself understood.

Thanks for reading all of these.

Comment: You're missing a few key points here, I would recommend to go through the entire [Elm Architecture](https://github.com/evancz/elm-architecture-tutorial) tutorial first, it covers this specific topic in [Example 4](https://github.com/evancz/elm-architecture-tutorial#example-4-a-fancier-list-of-counters)

Comment: I already have read the tutorials, what I want to do is prevent Counter.Model being part of the CounterList.Model.

Comment: Using the Elm Architecture, your CounterList.Model will need to carry the state of a list of Counter.Models. Elm is a pure functional language, so you can't access anything except what was passed into a function. Therefore, in your example, the `Contents.Content` needs to have a field of type `Counter.Model` in order to render `Counter.view`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to all of you commenting.

After going through the [Elm Architecture tutorial](https://github.com/evancz/elm-architecture-tutorial) again, I noticed that its code structure is somehow different from the one used in [Elm Tutorial Gitbook](http://www.elm-tutorial.org). And for my app, it's better to use the one described in **Elm Architecture tutorial**.

There is the difference:

- **Elm Architecture** defines `Model` `Action` `update` `view` and `init` for all the sub module

  - *Utility modules are not counted as **sub module** here*
  - *some of the `Model` `Action`... may be omitted when it is quite simple*
- **Elm Tutorial** puts the *Models* and *Actions* of a certain concept into separate `.elm` files and has a few *View* files (`Edit.elm` `List.elm` etc.) which are importing the *Models* and *Actions*

When a certain concept's different views depend on its `Model` ONLY(or its variant, `List Model` for example), we can adopt the structure used in the **Elm Tutorial**. The reason is any high level modules using that concept would initialize the `Model` as a part of `HighLevelModel`. But when there is a view that not only depends on its own 'Model' but also needs another sub module, we can not use the structure of **Elm Tutorial**. In this case, that view can be treated as a new module (in fact, it is a new module), so it should have its own `Model` type and be imported by the high level module.